# Using FindArgMax in NSolve with dependant variables

Tags: equation-solving, mathematical-optimization, physics

I have a function for a current through a series circuit containing a capacitor(c) and a resistor(r) and a battery(Ebatt) when the capacity increases from c0 to c.

```
c0 = 3.27*^-11;
Ebatt = 250;
tmin = 250*10^-6;
imin = 1.00*10^-6;
ifunc[Ebatt_, t_, c_, R_] := Ebatt*(1 - (c0/c))*Exp[-t/(c*R)]/R
(* ifunc[Ebatt, tmin, c, maxR]=imin *)
(* maxR=FindArgMax[ifunc[Ebatt, tmin, c, r],r] *)
```

the capacity c and the resistance maxR is the unknown constants, maxR being the resistance when the current reaches its maximum point.

```
c_estimate= c0*1.05
maxR[c_] := First[FindArgMax[ifunc[Ebatt, tmin, c, r], {r, 1*10^6, 10^7}]]

c_change = c /. NSolve[{ifunc[Ebatt, tmin, c, maxR[c_estimate]] == imin, c > c0}, {c}];
new_Rmax = maxR[c_change]
c_change = c /. NSolve[{ifunc[Ebatt, tmin, c, maxR[c_change]] == imin, c > c0}, {c}];
```

I can get the solution of c and maxR by estimating the first c and iterating over the c_change function but i can't find how to use maxR in a single NSolve function.

How do i Solve for c in a  single NSolve function when maxR is dependant on c?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Syntax errors(?): `c_estimate` and `c_change` each represent a `Pattern[]`, not a variable.  The underscore is called a `Blank[]`.

Comment: Your equations are not of the form that `NSolve` is designed to deal with. You probably want `FindRoot`.

Comment: I feel like i'm getting closer to the solution of finding Rmax by using FindMaximum instead of using FindArgM. FindMaximum[{ifunc[Ebatt, tmin, c, r], 
  ifunc[Ebatt, tmin, c, r] == imin, c > c0}, {c, r}] I feel like the main issue is not finding the correct rmax